# Is there vbspace in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I mean we have `vbnewline`, `vblf`, `vbcr`, `vbtab`.

Is there `vbspace`?

I mean this may sound trivial. Just press the space bar button or do ""

The thing is,

Space is unseen. Code will be clearer if we put vbspace.

Also there are many kind of space. Non breaking space etc.

So is there such thing? Where can I see list of vb special characters?

Comment: I also disagree with your assertion.  The reason that those constants exist is that those characters have no visual representation of their own.  In C-based languages they are represented with escape characters, e.g. "\r\n", "\n", "\r" and "\t".  That's why there's no corresponding constants in C#.  A space does have a visual representation so having such a constant to represent it is unnecessary.  I can tell you for a fact that you will actually be making your code harder to read for most people.

Comment: those are all just constants - you could define your own if you think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. This page lists all of the `vbFoo` constant values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants_fields(v=vs.110).aspx

I disagree with your notion that "code will be clearer",  but if you really want:

```
Public Const vbSpace As String = " "
```

Comment: How do you get that site? what terms do you look for?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`space()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6ethaxs(v=vs.90).aspx):- *Returns a string consisting of the specified number of spaces*

```
Dim TestString As String 
' Returns a string with 1 spaces.
TestString = Space(1)
' Returns a string with 10 spaces.
TestString = Space(10)
' Inserts 10 spaces between two strings.
TestString = "Hi" & Space(10) & "Sharen Eayrs"
```